# can't access other files from my index page when using Express

Tags: node.js, express, cloud9-ide

when putting up my index.pug page on cloud9, i can access the page correctly using (appname).c9users.io/. however i am using external css and js files, however i get a bunch of 404 errors when i include the css and js files even though they are in the same folder as my index.pug page.

i thought this might be some stupid chmod permissioning error where i hadn't set up the cloud9 environment right but it wasn't. just putting up this question because i wasted a bunhc of time on it as an express newbie.

Comment: discovered this is a link of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why?rq=1

Comment: Also relevant: [Loading resources in express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505215/loading-resources-in-express/34506377#34506377) and [css and jss files are not loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341995/at-node-express-execution-css-and-js-files-are-not-loading/39342125#39342125)

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer is i forgot to set up the routing for other files. ie

```
app.use('/public', express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));
```

for longer form explanation see http://www.clementinejs.com/tutorials/tutorial-beginner.html#AddingAdditionalElementstoIndex.html

hope this helps future me's

Comment: Yes.  It sounds like you didn't realize that Express serves NO files by default.  There must be a route that covers every file you want the web server to serve.  As you discovered, you can use a route with `express.static()` to cover all files in a given directory.

Comment: i assumed that because i already defined the '/' route to index.pug it would serve all the files in the same folder as my index.pug but it was a poor assumption. just throwing it up on SO to help future dolts like me